# Replace all instances of millimetres with inches, in thousand of cells

Tags: excel, replace, find

I have a spreadsheet with thousands of cells which will include something like:

> Pack of 50. 25mm x 50mm x 25mm. Ideal for all applications.

I need to convert all instances of measurements in millimetres to inches. The measurements aren't always in the same place, but will end with "mm".

I did think I could use a SUBSTITUTE function, with a list of the conversions like below:

> 25mm    63/64"

> 50mm    1 31/32 ″

That would then leave the text as

> Pack of 50. 63/64" x 1 31/32" x 63/64". Ideal for all applications.

Say the cell with the old text is A1, the mm text being searched for in column B, and the inch conversion is in column C. The function would then be:

> =SUBSTITUTE(A1,B:B,C:C)

But that doesn't appear to work. Is there any way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For your required recursive substitutions you'll need something like:

`=REDUCE(A1,B$1:B$10,LAMBDA(ξ,ζ,SUBSTITUTE(ξ,ζ,XLOOKUP(ζ,B$1:B$10,C$1:C$10))))`

Note that I have replaced your references to entire columns (`B:B`, `C:C`). Although these ranges may contain blanks without adversely affecting the result, they should nevertheless be kept to a minimum for performance reasons.